# C# как читать текст из .docx через поток

Tags: c#, .net, потоки-данных

Проблема возникает именно с `.docx` файлами, файлы `.txt` через `StreamReader` читаются довольно легко.

Вот метод:

```cs
public string DownloadToEditor(string FilePath)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FilePath, Encoding.Default))
            {
                return TextForEditor = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
    }
```

Как исправить? мне обязательно использовать какую то стороннюю библиотеку?

Comment: Сторонние библиотеки вам буду нужны если требуется работать с содержимым документа (объектная модель Word). Чтобы просто прочитать документ как текстовый файл смените кодировку.

Comment: Проблема ведь, как я понимаю, в том, что вы видите кучу непонятных символов после чтения?

Comment: Я не очень хорошо знаком с форматов DOCX, но вроде это сжатый файл и перед тем, как работать с содержимым нужно выполнить распаковку.

Comment: Да, обязательно использовать стороннюю библиотеку. Docx - это не текстовый файл. Это зазипованный xml.

Comment: Конечно .docx не будет читать, переведи .docx в pdf или открой в браузере. Думаю после этого сможешь открыть.

Comment: И что потом автор будет делать с pdf? Этот формат он тоже не сможет прочитать как простой текст. А разве браузеры умеют показывать docx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> мне обязательно использовать какую то стороннюю библиотеку?

Да, обязательно. Ну или можешь сам написать парсер файлов по специфицациям майкрсофт, но подозреваю что это займет у тебя лет 5. Зато без сторонних библиотек, как того желаешь.

Подойдет [Open XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c6e744e5-36e9-45f5-8d8c-331df206e0d0&DisplayLang=en).

Использовать **Interop** путь крайне не советую. Слишком много сложностей + ограничение что бы сам офис стоял на машине.

Можно воспользоватся нюгетами OpenXML или обертками вокруг OpenXML. Например, можно воспользоватся оберткой [DocX от xceed](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/docx) **(именно сюда обрати свой взор! Именно это я советую больше всего)**

Comment: Я считываю текст с помощью OpenXML: 

`try
   {
    using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(FilePath as string, true))
    {
     //Получаем весь текст из тела файла
     TextForEditor = document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.InnerText;
    }
   }
   catch (FileFormatException)
   {
    form.MessError("Неверно указан формат, или файл пуст");
    TextForEditor = null;
   }
   return TextForEditor;`
Но текст получается в одну строчку, как это можно исправить?

Comment: Я советую использовать обертки вокруг него, а не сам OpenXml. Он не совсем дружелюбен, на сколько я знаю) Лучше воспользуйся той последней линкой библиотеки